# GET is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, http

I am calling values form file written in php using ajax call in angular, the code is ..

```
  var occurence = $http({
  url:'getSelectFields_api.php',
  method: GET,
  params:{"api":"TRUE",
             "functionName" : "getFields" ,
              "field_id":"occur",
             "list_id":"occurrence",
             "empty_title":"SKIP",
             "data_type":1,}

}).success(function(data){

     $scope.occurences =data;
     console.log(occurences);
     });
```

and in the console what i'm getting is 'GET is not defined ......' Please guide me .. 
Thanks ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed the string definition in there. It should be `'GET'`

Comment: it' a syntax error , oh ok thank u ,